# closure compiler and Prototype.js: dangerous use of this

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, google-closure-compiler

I wrote some javascript code relying on Prototype.js.

Prototype.js's way to define classes is the following:

```
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
});
```

All the keys passed to `Class.create` will be added to `Person.prototype`. With this mechanism Prototype.js is able to offer inheritance. [[link]](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance.html)

---

Closure compiler now complains because it thinks that those `initialize` and `say` functions are "neither a prototype method nor marked as a constructor". [[link, check: JCS_UNSAFE_THIS]](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref#JSC_UNSAFE_THIS)

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

While not an exact duplicate question, the answer would be.

Reference John's answer to [reformat javascript to accommodate google-closure-compiler's namespace flattening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890325/reformat-javascript-to-accomodate-google-closure-compilers-namespace-flattening/17951029#17951029)